# Get value of xml node in c#

Tags: c#, xml

XML

```
 <table>
<row>
    <field name="ID">22490</field>
    <field name="post_date">2014-03-24 09:55:50</field>
    <field name="post_title">Joe Bloggs</field>
    <field name="post_status">Live</field>
    <field name="post_modified">2017-07-31 15:33:46</field>
</row>
<row>
    <field name="ID">29078</field>
    <field name="post_date">2017-08-01 08:19:57</field>
    <field name="post_title">Mary Poppins</field>
    <field name="post_status">auto-draft</field>
    <field name="post_modified">2017-08-01 08:19:57</field>
</row><table>
```

Im trying to loop through the xml above, how can I get the value "Joe Bloggs" from the post_title field above?

Here's what I have so far:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("C:\\myxmlfile.xml");

XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("row");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    string post_title = /// how can i get this
    string post_status = /// how can i get this
}
```

I can loop through the nodelist however, I cant get the value within each field.

Comment: "just cant assign the value to a variable" - what do you mean by that? Can you post a [mcve]? (That's clearly not the full XML doc, as otherwise it would have two root elements.) I'd also strongly recommend using LINQ to XML, but that's a different matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I resolved the issue:

```
XmlNodeList orgFields = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//row");



        foreach (XmlNode org in orgFields)
        {
            post_title = org.ChildNodes[2].InnerText;
            post_status = org.ChildNodes[3].InnerText;

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if property name is what you are expected

```
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    string temp = XmlNode.SelectSingleNode("field[@name='post_title']").InnerText;
}
```

This will work for sure.

Comment: .InnerText returns a string so can explicitly declare temp.  It's a bit more readable like that.

Comment: In my example the node.attributes collection is empty, the values are within the childnodes

Comment: Edit seems to be removed current element from loop in string evaluation & now it does not work

Comment: @PranavSingh old one. I am not sure why i edited this -------->
 foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    string post_title = node.Attributes["Name"].Value;
    if(post_title == "post_title")
    {
        var temp = node.InnerText; // This will have your value. Store it where ever you want to store
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use xPath as well.

```
        XmlNodeList postTitleFields = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//field[@name='post_title']");
        foreach (XmlNode postTitleField in postTitleFields)
        {
            string post_title = postTitleField.InnerText;
        }
```

Comment: How can this be used to get multiple values within the node?

Comment: @Dez79 But this answers your question exactly.  If you're looking for something else, please update the question to reflect that.  postTitleFields is a collection so it does contain multiple values for post_title.