# extract attribute value and node value from parent node in XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<keywords>
   <keyword subject="x">a</keyword>
   <keyword subject="y">b</keyword>
</keywords>
```

I would like to extract the node and attribute values from the above XML example like so:

```
a|x, b|y
```

Is this possible in C#?

Comment: You can use `XmlReader` to parse the XML and extract what is required.

Comment: I am sure I can thanks or I can use linq to xml. However, usually one can only extract node(s) values or attribute values. I am just not sure how to use, fro example, xmlreader to extract combinations like this ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value of xml node in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45489734/get-value-of-xml-node-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @ZulqarnainJalil this is not related at all!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `LinqToXML` to achieve your goal. Like this

```
XElement element = XElement.Parse(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
                                    <keywords>
                                         <keyword subject=""x"">a</keyword>
                                         <keyword subject=""y"">b</keyword>
                                    </keywords>");

var result = String.Join(", ", (from d in element.Descendants("keyword")
                     select $"{d.Value}|{d.Attribute("subject").Value}"));
```

`result` string: `a|x, b|y`

This code sample is just demonstrating right direction and concept. Don't forget to implement all necessary checks and border cases (for example, is `subject` attribute required?).

Hope that helps.

Comment: @cs0815 was it helpful for you? If it was, please, mark as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try using XElement to do that, ist as simpel as

`XElement myXml = XElement.Load("xmlFile Location)`,

then you can use linq to query your dataSet, and just store the values inside some List that you can format into your desired output.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement?view=netframework-4.8
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/xelement-class-overview

You can use the Attributes method to get an XAttribute back from the Element(your specific node) and its value

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xattribute?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XDocument for quick data retrieval (replace.Parse with .Load for a file path):

```
var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
string result = document
                .Element("keywords")
                .Elements("keyword")
                .Aggregate<XElement, string>(string.Empty, (res, element)
                    => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(res) ? res : res + ", ") + element.Value + "|" + element.Attribute("subject").Value);
```

If the xml spec is yours you should probably make xml model classes and deserialize the xml into them.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an answer using `XmlReader` class in `C# Console app`

```
 XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"[Location of your XML file here..]"); 
  while (reader.Read())
  {
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
      if (reader.Name.ToLower() == "keyword")
      {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);

        if (reader.HasAttributes)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(reader.GetAttribute("subject"));
        }
      }
    }
  }
  Console.ReadKey();
```